# Who was the first person to bear the name "Lannister"?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I know Loreon I Lannister was the very first Lannister to rule as King of the rock but of course it doesn't mean he was the very first person to ever bear the name Lannister.

I'm trying to find out which descendant of Lann was the first person to derive the name "Lannister" from the name "Lann". The book doesn't mention who the first Lannisters were before Loreon's time?

Even if Lann the clever was just a historical myth, it's obvious someone used his first name as an idea to formulate the name Lannister. Question is who?

Answer (score 14):

We don't know any Lannister before Lann the clever ( and we don't even know if he *was* called a Lannister), who founded House Lannister and the first King of the Rock, Loreon I Lannister (Loreon the Lion).

This info is given in the World of Ice and Fire. It is also said (rumored more like it) that Lann had a hundred sons

> Lann the Clever supposedly lived to the age of 312, and sired a hundred bold sons and a hundred lissome daughters, all fair of face, clean of limb, and blessed with hair "as golden as the sun.
>
> <sub>The World of Ice and Fire; The Westerlands.</sub>

Besides these, there is speculation. It is possible that Lann started calling himself a Lannister, or one of his many sons.

We also don't who the parents of Loreon where, so we cannot know for sure if there were other Lannisters before him.

Comment: We don't even know if Lann the Clever existed or is just a myth.

Comment: Well, he probably wasn't called "Lannister," since he was Lann.

Answer (score 6):

**Other Canon**
From *[The World of Ice and Fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_of_Ice_%26_Fire)*, it seems as though the author, George R. R. Martin, and his co-authors (Elio Garcia and Linda Antonsson) want us to believe that it was one of Lann's descendents, given that he was titled posthumously:

> Lann the Clever never called himself a king, as best we know, though some tales told centuries later have conferred that styling on him posthumously. The first true Lannister king we know of is Loreon Lannister, also known as Loreon the Lion 
> <sub>*-The World of Ice and Fire: The Westerlands.*</sub>

**Books Canon**
From the main books, I think GRRM wants us to believe that it was Lann The Clever who was the first Lannister. Or at least Lann's first immediate descendent (being that they would have been a **Lann**ister.

From *A Game of Thrones*:

> He opened to the section on House Lannister once more, and turned the pages slowly, hoping against hope that something would leap out at him. The Lannisters were an old family, tracing their descent back to Lann the Clever, a trickster from the Age of Heroes who was no doubt as legendary as Bran the Builder
> <sub>*-A Song of Ice and Fire: Book One - A Game of Thrones, Chapter Twenty-Seven (Eddard VI).*</sub>

And from *A Storm of Swords*:

> “Your place.” The voice echoed; it was a hundred voices, a thousand, the voices of all the Lannisters since Lann the Clever, who’d lived at the dawn of days. 
> <sub>*-A Song of Ice and Fire: Book Three - A Storm of Swords, Chapter Forty-Four (Jaime VI).*</sub>

And from *A Feast For Crows*:

> The Lannisters of Casterly Rock remain the principal support of King Tommen’s claim to the Iron Throne. They boast of descent from Lann the Clever, the legendary trickster of the Age of Heroes.
> <sub>*-A Song of Ice and Fire: Book Four - A Feast For Crows, Appendix.*</sub>

Comment: What's the context to the "Your place" quote? I'm asking because I can't help imagining it as Tywin's booming answer to Chataya flirtily asking "Your place or mine?", and I want to get that image out of my head...

Comment: @user568458 Lol. It was in Jamie's weirwood dream. Just after he left Harrenhall and before he went back to save Brienne from the bear.